# Token encode/decode issue - Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have problem using UrlEncoder and UrlDecoder.

It looks like this:
Example of token:

```
3vv3XIvofg3KIoMjLwU07329C6dsk8HJceuDT2F5jOwox2hyqAnL+03TPej/lW4TCeFWRadRkPKgW0aGxq+9B1VZLMvoevyFfaVXhvzIyLF8AN3NDCqk0hoqb51wlGtb4hUvOYKq5b63wuW2pfssr9O0dgCEK4VZz8QZ4jRpxZw=
```

I set token on Customer in my Spring Application. Then I encode token to use it in url:

```
String token = // generated by mechanism
String encodedToken = UrlEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8");

String url = "https://myapp.url?token=" + encodedToken;
```

I receive token as a @RequestParam. Then the token is decoded by UrlDecoder

```
String decodedToken = UrlDecoder.decode(token, "UTF-8");
```

The problem is as follows:
Sometimes it works correctly and I am able to find user by token, but sometimes I have error, because decoded token is invalid, and it looks different than token. What is the problem? It is strange because sometimes it works, sometimes not

Comment: What kind of characters can the token contain? And how long is the token?

Comment: @qutax I was editing my post to show example of token

Comment: so only `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `+`, `/` and `=`? Sorry, but one example token is not enough, if it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Can you include an exampe of a token that decoded successfully and a token that did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token will already be decoded by Spring because of the `@RequestParam` annotation.
If the token contains a `+`, the second decoding will replace the `+` with a  (white space).

I am assuming you are using `java.net.URLEncoder` and `java.net.URLDecoder`? As the Javadoc of the `encode(String, String)` and `decode(String, String)` methods describes, they encode to and decode from the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. In this format, the `+` is a special character replacing a space.
So a `+` will be *en*coded to `%2B` and *de*coded to . Because Spring will already have taken care of the decoding, the `%2B` will be a `+` again. Your second decoding translates it to a  and the tokens won't match anymore.

Comment: Yep, yestarday I realized that it is so. Thanks for help. I removed decoding and it works